# Pandas Python Integrate Rows, Divide by Variable then Multiple by 100

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, division

I have an investment portfolio where each security is given a percentage allocation.  I want to use pandas to group the securities into Equity and Fixed Income.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
invest_equity = 'Invest - Equity'
invest_fixedincome = 'Invest - Fixed Income'
df['Name'] = ['Invest - Equity ','Invest - Equity', 'Invest - Fixed Income', 'Invest - Fixed Income']
df['Allocation %'] = ['50','10','10','30']
```

So far I have been able to sum the groups and store the variable:

```
x = df[df['Name']==invest_equity]['Allocation %'].sum()
y = df[df['Name']==invest_fixedincome]['Allocation %'].sum()
```

From here I do not know how to get the desired result.  I have tried the following which doesn't give an error but also does not update the excel sheet.

```
df[df['Name']==invest_fixedincome]['Allocation %'].div(x).mul(100)
```

The end result should be:

```
df['Allocation %'] = ['83.33','16.67','25','75']
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using correct data types? `ʼ3.5ʼ` is a string/object not a numeric float

Comment: my xlsx sheet is numerical numbers.  I did not know how to represent them for a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
df['Allocation %'] = (df.assign(**{'Allocation %': df['Allocation %'].astype(int),
                                   'Name': df['Name'].str.strip()})
                      .groupby('Name')['Allocation %'].transform(lambda col: col / col.sum())
                      .mul(100).round(2))
```

```
print(df)

                    Name  Allocation %
0      Invest - Equity           83.33
1        Invest - Equity         16.67
2  Invest - Fixed Income         25.00
3  Invest - Fixed Income         75.00
```

Comment: This works.  The only problem is that some of the allocations sum to less than 100 after.  Still better than manually doing all the work.  Is there any way to build a check sum and adjust one of the numbers to equal 100?